# how to get json from this webservice http://docs.apis.is/

Tags: php, ajax, json, curl

I'm having trouble to connect to docs.apis.is with php curl. Could anyone help get the connection with php and save the resource to json file witch I can work from.

This is what I have done so far

```
<?php
    $service_url ='http://apis.is/cinema';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($curl_response === false) {
     $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     die('Error occured during curl exec:'. var_export($info));
    }
   curl_close($curl);

   //get file and insert it into json
   $json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   json_encode($curl, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   file_put_contents('json/cinema_data.json', $curl_response);

 ?>
```

I dont seem do make the connection. So if you could help me to solve this and turn me in the right way to use ajax to display the json text to my html page.

Thank you

Comment: have you enabled curl in your server??

Comment: The response is returning JSON data and it looks good, check if you have CURL installed.

Comment: The problem are typos. His code is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
curl_close($curl);
$json_string = json_encode(json_decode($curl_response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents('json/cinema_data.json', $json_string);
```

Note `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` improves readability of the JSON data *for humans*, but it also makes the file a lot bigger.

Also note that `$curl_response` is already a JSON string, it is just not "prettyfied".